# How can I use multiple providers to provide content for dmstags.tsx in ReactJS with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a reactJS newbie. I have these this issue that I can't seem to get around. I :

1. This is the App.tsx file:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
  import { HomeProvider} from "./institutions/dashboard_pages/HomeProvider";
  import DMainTags from "./institutions/layouts/dashboard_main_tags";

  const App: React.FC = () => {
    let content;
    // @ts-ignore
    return (
      <>
        <Router>
          <DMainTags content={content}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/institution/dashboard" element={<HomeProvider></HomeProvider>} />
            </Routes>
          </DMainTags>
        </Router>
      </>
    );

}

export default App;
```

2. This is the HomeProvider.tsx file:

```
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import localForage from 'localforage';

interface HomeContentProps {

    content: React.ReactNode;

}

export const HomeContext = createContext<HomeContentProps>({
    content: null,
});

export const HomeProvider: React.FC = () => {
    const [content, setContent] = useState<React.ReactNode>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchContent().then((data) => {
            setContent(data)
        });
    }, []);

    return (

        <HomeContext.Provider value={{content}}>
            <div> Hello world! </div>
        </HomeContext.Provider>


    );
};

async function fetchContent(): Promise<React.ReactNode> {

    try {
        let token = await localForage.getItem<string>('token');
        let clinic_id = await localForage.getItem('clinic_id');
        let staff_id = await localForage.getItem('staff_id');
        let institution_id = await localForage.getItem('institution_id');

        if (!token || !clinic_id || !staff_id || !institution_id) {
            window.location.href = './logout';
            return null;
        }

        // @ts-ignore
        const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Api-key": token,
                "Content-Type": "application.json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "clinic_id": clinic_id,
                "staff_id": staff_id,
                "institution_id": institution_id
            })
        }

        let dash_url = "";
        const response = await fetch(dash_url, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();

        if(data.status === "error"){

            //load error module


        }else if(data.status === "success"){

            return data.data

        }else{

            //conn-fail error module


        }
    } catch (error) {
        // failed to fetch
    }
```

3. Finally this is the dmtags.tsx file:

```
import React from "react";
import DashboardHeader from "./dashboard_header";
import DashboardMainContent from "./dahsborad_main";
import SideMenu from "./dashboard_menu";
import {LordIconElement} from "lord-icon";
import DashboardFooter from "./dashboard_footer";``

const DMainTags: React.FC<{content: React.ReactNode}> = ({content}) => {

    // @ts-ignore
    // @ts-ignore
    return(
        <>
            <div id="layout-wrapper">
                <DashboardHeader></DashboardHeader>

                <div id="removeNotificationModal" className="modal fade zoomIn" tabIndex={-1} aria-hidden="true">
                    <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="NotificationModalbtn-close"> </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">
                                <div className="mt-2 text-center">
                                    <LordIconElement src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/gsqxdxog.json" trigger="loop" colors="primary:#f7b84b,secondary:#f06548" style={{width:'100', height:'100'}} />
                                    <div className="mt-4 pt-2 fs-15 mx-4 mx-sm-5">
                                        <h4>Are you sure ?</h4>
                                        <p className="text-muted mx-4 mb-0">Are you sure you want to remove this Notification ?</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center mt-4 mb-2">
                                    <button type="button" className="btn w-sm btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn w-sm btn-danger" id="delete-notification">
                                        Yes, Delete It!
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <SideMenu></SideMenu>

                <div className="vertical-overlay">

                </div>

                <div className="page-content">
                    <div className="container-fluid">

                        {content}

                    </div>
                </div>

                {/*Footer Here*/}
                <DashboardFooter></DashboardFooter>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default DMainTags;
```

what did I do wrong?

I have multiple providers that i want to provide content for dmstags.tsx instead of having to create multiple files.